# Using reflection to get attribute names in struct returns value__

Tags: c#, reflection, struct, attributes

I want to populate a combo box with all of the available item types in my struct `ItemTypes`:

```
public enum ItemTypes
{
    Ore,
    Ice,
    Mineral,
    Pi
}
```

In order not to add a new item type in 2 places if I do have to add one eventually (not likely, but still could happen), I want to use reflection to populate that combo box instead of manually adding each item type in a list. This is how I do it:

```
private void InitItemTypeComboBox()
{
    ComboBoxItemTypes = new List<String>();

    foreach (var itemType in typeof(EveItem.ItemTypes).GetFields())
    {
        ComboBoxItemTypes.Add(itemType.Name);
    }

    SelectedComboBoxItemType = ComboBoxItemTypes.ElementAt(0);
}
```

Unfortunately, the `GetFields()` and `itemType.Name` functions return not only the 4 item types in my struct, it also returns `value__` as first field, so I have an extra element in my combo box that I do not want.

I have tried using the `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`, `BindingFlags.Public` and `BindingFlags.Instance` flags of the `GetFields()` together, but it still returns that first `value__` element that I don't want.

Is there a way to specify that I do not want this element other than by manually skipping the first element returned by `typeof(EveItem.ItemTypes).GetFields()`?

EDIT:

If it changes anything, my `ItemTypes` struct is nested inside another one of my public classes.

Comment: You should switch to `Enum.GetValues`

Comment: This works, you can add it as an answer, I will select it as answer to the question.

Comment: You can use an extension method for Enum which returns dictionary , see this: http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2015/03/binding-enum-with-dropdownlist-in.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use :`var t = typeof(ItemTypes).GetFields().Where(k => k.IsLiteral == true);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BindingFlags.Static` (see for example http://goo.gl/w3VndT)

So

```
typeof(EveItem.ItemTypes).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
```

Answer (score 1):

An easiest way to get values from an enum is to use a built-in `Enum.GetValues` method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues%28v=vs.100%29.aspx